Search and replace partial text/code in MyPHPAdmin within a MySQL "longtext" field
I have a Drupal v.10 website with PHPMyAdmin as the host server's database administration tool.
In the website the nodes for user posts contains a body field that is of the "longtext" format.
There is a html link code within each otherwise unique node that is commmon to each of these nodes in which I would like to globally change if possible.
The MySQL structure of the field are:
Name: body_value
Type: longtext
Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
Attributes:
Null: No
Default: None
I can of course search within the field and find all of the nodes containing the link code (example: "https://site1.com") within the body which may have thousands of words/characters within it.
Note: the actual change is a username that appends a link eg: "*https://website.com?User=NAMEtoREPLACE*"
But, if I need to change the link text from "https://site1.com" to "https://site2.net", I do not know if that is possible on a global scale as other than that (and some other text/code) each node is otherwise unique.
Can anyone provide a method to globally search within this field and replace each instance of the link while leaving the rest of the text/code in the node's field untouched?
I have only tried searching to find the nodes containing the subject text/code (link to be replaced).
I have never done a global search and replace like this and even wonder if it is possible!
In another question regarding replacing a URL, a similar answer was provided referencing a WordPress website. I am guessing that WP formats it's tables differently, therefore this question requires a different response. If I understand it, that post's answer referenced 'post_content' as the key to replacing only a portion of the filed's content:
To reiterate my issue:
I have a similar problem where my goal is to replace a partial URL string, but cannot find the correct syntax.
I am assuming the 'post_content' is the key to replacing only a portion of the Post's table field content. The full URL within the body text in a 'longtext' field is:
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/external-search?tag=**MYTAG1**&amp;keyword=John+Barry+music&amp;mode=blended">John Barry films, books, &amp; soundtracks</a>

Perhaps someone can assist?
Here is the syntax, and MySQL response where I seek to replace "tag=MYTAG1" with "MYTAG2":
UPDATE `node__body` SET `body_value` = REPLACE(`body_value`,'tag=MYTAG2') where body_value LIKE '%tag=MYTAG1%';


MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near ') where post_content LIKE '%tag=MYTAG1%'' at line 1


Seems that the replace function could be enough?
